# complicated custom $.Event in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i was just going through the modal.js plugin and came across the following line :

```
  var e = $.Event('shown.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })
```

now i guess the line is actually defining a custom event , i do understand custom event . to be honest , i understand in parts whats happening , but i can't say that i wholly understand that particular line , to begin with .

we are using $.Event () to create a custom event and then inside that we are naming the event `'shown.bs.modal'` and then we are passing a object literal as a 2nd parameter (to me it looks more of a object literal , with another object literal inside it), my problem is in understanding the `{ relatedTarget: _relatedTarget }` of the code . i fail to understand why line of code is necessary for the plugin , what functionality does this line serve ?

if i console.log `_relatedTarget` i get the following:

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

my line of difficulty can be found on git too : [line 99](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L99).

if one of you Javascript geniuses can explain to me whats happening on that line or even give me a rough idea ,  would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation to modals [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) and search for `relatedTarget`.

Your understanding of the code is right so far. It passes the reference of the clicked button to the event handler.

Then you can find which button was clicked inside of your event handler `$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { ... }`.

As the docs write it's handy if you like to show modals with different content depending on the clicked button. Then you can add a data-attribute to the button to append some infos for your modal.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/su5sjf09/). It's almost the code from the bootstrap documentation.

Comment: almost a month later , this makes a little more sense to me , classic answer! Thanks a Million.

Answer (score 1):

That's a namespaced event.

The event is called 'shown' and it's being namespaced 'bs.modal' to avoid conflicting with any other 'shown' event that may be defined. The _relatedTarget variable is being defined somewhere else up in the code. When it's passed through as an object to the custom event, it gets assigned to the event object. That way you can use it and reference it in a handler like:

```
$('something').on('shown',function(e) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);   // this was passed as that obj param
});
```

Hopefully that helps show an example. Also read up on:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

As an also edit:
You can specify a handler for shown.bs.modal and it would only get called when that specific 'shown' event is called. That way, anything else calling 'shown' would not trigger your handler.